# Android - Zebra printing problems ZPL (Image/PDF)

Tags: android, image, pdf, zebra-printers, zpl

I have some problems when trying to print a PDF or an image (png/jpg). I'm using a ZQ320 printer, zpl its it current device.language.
I get from an api a report in both png and pdf formats, both encoded in Base64

For the image, I been using the following code:

```
printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(printerConnection);
printer.printImage(ZebraImageFactory.getImage(bitmap), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), false);
```

But when it prints, it prints/skips a lot of the paper and then it prints the image but its size is really small. I've tried replacing the bitmap with a 20x20px black square to check if maybe the image is the problem, but I get the same result, a lot of white paper skipped and the square prints but seems smaller.

So I tried, sending the pdf to the printer with this. The `scaleMethod` I borrowed it from [here](https://github.com/ZebraDevs/LinkOS-Android-Samples/blob/PDFPrint/PDFPrint/app/src/main/java/com/zebra/pdfprint/SendPDF.java)

```
String scale = scalePrint(printerConnection, Uri.fromFile(file));
SGD.SET("apl.settings", scale, printerConnection);
printer.sendFileContents(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

But instead of printing the report it prints the information about the printer (serial number, program and other stuff). I've checked other methods from the example I found, and it seems I'm missing a  pdf virtual device for the printer, I've checked it with the `apl.enable` and it returns `none`.

I've trying other formats for the image and pdf but I still keep getting the same results. How can I fix it?

Comment: I've had that issue when the `device.language` was in `line_print`, but now its correctly in `zpl`. I tried storing the image in the tablet and then sending the filepath but i got the same result. Although I havent tried storing the image in the printer, I'll try it later, thanks for the reply!

Comment: Sorry its been a while, I tried storing the image but I couldnt get it to work. We finally contacted the technical support and they made us upgrade the printers firmware to allow it to support PDF files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I had was caused because the printer's firmware did not support PDF formats. When we contacted Zebra's  tech support, they told us to upgrade the firmware, and it worked fine